# Video with lower bitrate resulting from joining two video files

Tags: video, video-editor, video-quality, bitrate

I had a 595mb .MP4 video (data rate: 510 kbps, Total bitrate 638 kbps). And I joined it with another .MP4 youtube video with a lower quality(only the end part).. The resulting video file has a data rate of 389kbps and Total bitrate of 517 kbps.. The size is also significantly smaller; 494mb.. I used a program called Video Combiner.. And side by side I can see the original one is better quality looking.. so what am i doing wrong? any suggestions? I just wanna join 2 video files without loss of total quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program probably re-encoded the resulting video file from scratch and used whatever setting it considered okay.

If you want to have more control about the process *and/or* do not want it to re-encode the video at all (if both are of the same format), then I strongly suggest looking into ffmpeg for this.

For reference, https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate - the concat demuxer is what you want.

As the most simple example, copy both your video files (let's call them videoA.mp4 and videoB.mp4) into the same folder. Create a videos.txt file with just this content:

```
file videoA.mp4
file videoB.mp4
```

Now run ffmpeg with this command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i videos.txt -c copy videoOut.mp4
```

If all goes well this gives you a new file with both videos in one file, with the original encoding intact.

Comment: thank u ...this is absolutely what i was looking for.. but couldnt express properly to Google..   But ffmpeg is a big program, that can do many things which i will never use.. i dont suppose i would be able to find a smaller program that can do that using a GUI??

Comment: Hmm, maybe try this one https://ffqueue.bruchhaus.dk/Screenshots.aspx
I haven't used it myself but judging from the 9th picture it appears to have the concat functionality built into the GUI.

Comment: ok..       ✌    Thank u